# Deploying to GoogleAPP ENGINE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

on deploying my application to google app engine i encountered the following error when i try to click on the endpoints i have, is there away to solve this since i cant seem to do migrations on google app engine??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "api_rent_record" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ecord"."damaged", "api_rent_record"."faulty" FROM "api_rent_...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 760, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 678, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/rent_record/
Exception Value: relation "api_rent_record" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ecord"."damaged", "api_rent_record"."faulty" FROM "api_rent_...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Looks like the database isn't migrated. Did you follow the instructions from here, https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Comment: yes i followed the instructions but i don't know what's the issue

Comment: Please tell us how you migrated and how you have your migrations defined.

Comment: well i actually took a look again at my settings seems that was the issue everything is actually working now